# How to fix attic sheathing being wet causing mold

Tags: insulation, attic, mold, ventilation

I have mold in my attic. I have a mold remediation company that is going to come out and fix it but they will only warranty the work if the underlying issue is resolved.

The roof sheathing is at 100% moisture for most of my attic. There is also slight moisture on the top of the insulation. Roof is 4 years old. Roofer came back out and said it's not leaking as that wouldn't make sense that the entire roof sheathing is moist. Roof has open soffits and ridge vent. Clearly there is too much moisture up there.

There is one bathroom vent that runs through the attic and out the gable on the side of the house, originally it ran into the soffit but I changed that so the moisture doesn't get pulled back in.

Outside of the whole roof being bad, what would cause the sheathing to be so moist? How can I fix this moisture issue so the mold doesn't come back?

Comment: Are you venting combustion exhaust (which includes water vapor) inside the house? Humidity condensing on the cold sheathing seems most likely given the new roof.

Comment: Either your ventilation(soffits and/or ridge vent) is blocked or your roof is leaking.  The other choice is you are in a 100% humidly location.  This is assuming you do not have insulation on the roof deck/sheeting

Comment: I don't think there is any combustion exhaust venting in the house. Everything seems to be vented outside properly including both bathroom vents and the dryer. I did just watch videos about looking for and sealing entries into the attic including around cabling/wiring. I did mean to add the house is in NH. No AC, baseboard heating so no airflow inside the house. I can see light on the soffits and ridge vent so it seems like they are not blocked. No insulation on sheathing, just on the floor of the attic.

Comment: Does not make sense.  Your attic should be dry with what you say.  Either your mold(if not tested) is something else(dirt/ink stains) plus the moisture test is wrong, or you have a source of moisture.  Do you have any water supply pipes in the attic?  Usually a very bad idea in NH.

Comment: I can imagine a bad ridge vent install being the root of this evil. My only other theory is a bad moisture meter, where that's very easy to test (use a dry piece of wood). The roofer's claim aligns with his interests, so it's not as reliable as a statement against his interests.

Comment: Something is letting humidified air outside of the envelope (the conditioned 'inside' of your house) and into your attic which then condenses on the cold plywood. Either stop going up there and having the door open, find a vent that's letting it get in (up) from inside the house, or from wall cavities below with no insulation in them. Or have 10~20k in spray foam put in to make it part of the envelope. Or batt insulation and drywall.

Comment: *I have a mold remediation company that is going to come out* and spay the stuff you could just go buy at the store? What does their company actually do if it isn't "remediation" of the *actual* problem, and *then* spend the 20 minutes spraying the stuff? (oh I guess, pull all the wet insulation and then spray?... and then put it back? yuck) You're going pay for a warranty that would be unnecessary if it couldn't *do* that anymore, so.... Pull the insu, spray the stuff, put new insu, then drywall.

Comment: Roof is vented properly and 4yo; prob not their fault. And you're dealing with a company that only wants to come and do the easy part, and isn't even willing be on the legal hook to tell you what's going on here. An HVAC guy would tell you to hire a contractor because you've a lot of work to do here. Any part of your house half inside and half outside the envelope *will cause this problem* and has little to do with their job either.

Comment: Actually, you just need a drywaller who's willing to do insulation, and spray the stuff first. If not then you hire whoever they say *their* insulation guy is, which honestly is better than any 'warranty'. Which would ultimately be better than w/e hacks an HVAC guy can come up with to 'fix' this (the attic would now be a part of the house). *Then* you have them come and put a supply and a return duct if possible. - Should prob pull the inslu yourself, use box fans and wait a few days, spray, then have guys come.

Comment: Just to confirm, you don't have insulation against the roof sheathing, correct? I'm assuming this is a finished ceiling with insulation, then your open ventilated attic space with gable, soffit, and ridge vents, and above that is open sheathing. If that's not correct please advise.

Comment: Used two different moisture meters and both show the same thing. The wood also feels moist to the touch. I agree the roofer isn't going to easily admit if he is at fault. I finally found another roofer that will come look at it (2 wouldn't as they said it's unethical to review another persons work).
It's definitely mold as it is creeping into the upstairs bathroom and closet also. There are two PVC pipes up there. My best guess is water vent pipe as it goes straight out the roof and no water is in it. mold company is needed as it is covering over half of the roof, way to much to tackle alone

Comment: I went through the attic today and spray foamed all of the holes I can find from cabling, in between joists and drywall where gaps appeared to be. I foil taped all of the tiny holes on the bathroom vent that may be pushing moisture up there. Hopefully this helps at least a little. KMJ you are correct about layout. Talked to spray foam company about removing the insu and making the attic part of the envelope. Estimate is around 8-9k. Selling the house within a year and already have numerous $10k+ projects done in 4 years...roof, driveway, deck, hot water tank...not trying to do anymore

Comment: Here are some pictures of it. https://imgur.com/7uls3eC https://imgur.com/luBO9J6 https://imgur.com/DV9HVo3 https://imgur.com/4jcVyqD

Comment: I'd get a flir iphone attachment and take a look at the thermals in the attic.  you can see air leaks as a cold attic will show where the hot air from the house is coming in.  getting RH readings in the house and the attic will also help.  sheathing doesn't look too bad.  mold remediation companies mostly exist due to fear mongering over mold.  I'd fix the moisture issue and just use a mold inhibiting paint on the wood that looks the worst.  mold grows on trees and in soil.  there are a few specific kinds of mold that are really bad but they are rare and you'd need a lab test to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but rather an investigative suggestion.

You need to monitor the temperature, humidity, and dew point (the critical parameter here) in your attic over a period of time.  Such sensors are available from companies such as Govee (not a product endorsement) for around $15.  You just set this device in your attic (or other space) and it logs temperature, humidity, & dew point over time.  You can then access this log remotely using Blue Tooth and an app on your cell phone.

Most attics in humid climates probably have some moisture condensation in them when the temperature of the roof or other surface drops below the dew point.  But with proper ventilation, this moisture should evaporate when the dew point drops (rising temperature or dropping humidity).

Comment: I purchased a 2 pack. Hopefully this can provide some info. Thanks!